# Jquery function that replaces characters with images

Tags: jquery, html, fonts

Is it a good idea to use a jquery function that replaces each character from a text to custom character images?

For example: when calling the function, you must pass as argument which element you want to have the characters replaced, and jquery will do (if the given element contains "hello world")

```
<img src="h.png"> 
<img src="e.png">
<img src="l.png"> 
<img src="l.png"> 
<img src="o.png"> 
<img src="space.png"> 
<img src="w.png"> 
<img src="o.png"> 
<img src="r.png"> 
<img src="l.png"> 
<img src="d.png">
```

Will this trick slow down my page too much?

ps: I want to use a png image for each character rather than a font file because there is going to be some special effects applied in these images that would be impossible to do with simple font.

Comment: What are the visually impaired going to do with your incomprehensible pile of images?

Comment: If you preload the images it won't slow down the page, but what special effects are you applying?  I have a feeling there is a better way.

Comment: My 2 cents are to use css sprites to improve performance. Take mo's advice and make sure you keep your actual text on the page.

Comment: Screen readers will read HTML source and because it'll be replaced by javascript there shouldn't be a problem for visually impaired. Using sprite and/or preload you can overcome "slow down" issue. Any other problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem—as mu mentioned—is that this will affect accessibility: vision impaired people can use readers that parse web pages and read the content back to them.

And yes, this will slow down page load times immensely—now your browser has to request a new image for each character in your page.

Comment: Why will it affect search engines' attempts to parse the page when the substitution is done via JavaScript/jQuery after the page loads?

Comment: @AdamRackis: I agree about vision impaired people, but 1) you can zoom in / zoom out from the page, 2) there are at least two ways of avoiding problem with multiple requests (and they are: using sprites, or base64-encoding images within HTML).

Comment: @Tadeck - yeah - of course you can zoom in, I'm not sure what I was thinking.  As far as neat workarounds like base-64 encodings, that would surely work, but it's far from what OP was originally asking.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everyone. I don't know what effect do you planning but there might be a better solution. Anyway, if you decided to go that way here is an example;

```
var text = $('div').text(), i, il= text.length, result = [], char;
for(i=0;i<il;i++) {
    char = text.charAt(i);
    if(char === " ") {
        char = "space";
    }
    result.push('<img src="' + char + '.png" alt="' + char + '" />');
}
$('div').html(result.join(''));
```

jsFiddle example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/x4bVv/).